# Mac App Store Dialogs vs Full Screen Window

Tags: macos, cocoa, in-app-purchase, nswindow

My app got rejected because the dialogs to handle in-app purchases are behind my transparent full screen window. You can still click them, but it's not user-friendly.

How would I handle this? Is there a way to alter the way these dialogs are presented, or should I change the properties of my own window?

I'm talking about these dialogs (the grid is what's drawn on my main window) :

[image]

Comment: I currently am changing the level of the `NSWindow` to `NSFloatingWindowLevel`. This is of course not a great solution, but it's enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the window level to a lower value so the dialogs appear on top when starting the store request and reset it to it's previous value after the request completes. Or you could exit full screen mode to make the store request. They may be more annoyed by the transparent window which can be confusing more than the window order.

Comment: Dialogs and Sheets are both NSWindow objects. So whatever you accessing in the dialog is the same if it is presented in a dialog or a sheet.

Comment: The thing is, I'm talking bout the dialogs that I don't control, the ones that get shown when I use the StoreKit API. They are not created by my own classes, and I'm not sure if there's a way to access them.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
@interface FullscreenWindow : NSWindow
@end

@implementation FullscreenWindow
-(id) init
{
    // some init code here...
    [self setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel+1];
    return self;
}
@end
```